# How to deregister a parathread?

Tags: parachain, cumulus

If I want to de register a parathread I have previously registered, which steps should I follow ?

What happens with the deposit ?

Answer (score 7):

In order to deregister one parathread a call [`deregister`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L257) needs to be sent to the relay chain.

Origin must be one of the following:

- root
- the para owner (depends on lock status)
- the para itself

The para to deregister must be a parathread.

This call will proceed freeing all the data previously registered for that para, and consequently all deposits paid for that storage will be returned to the relevant address.

Answer (score -1):

I can't register my parathread.

Origin must be one of the following:

- the para owner

Extrinsic History：
https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/0xfaff3ab8e13b9aff79c3b53a0f8e853fc222520b1b162bba26db8ce6744b69c6

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In your scenario, the paraId is locked, check storage item `registrar.paras(2017)`.
So that the owner can only take action when this lock is not active.

Comment: how to unlock a paraId.